# init.d tomcat6 script

Tags: tomcat, scripting, startup

I "installed" tomcat on ubuntu by just unzipping it. Is there a standard script I can use for /etc/init.d/tomcat? Or do I need to create one?

Currently I have created one that works, but I didn't know if there was a more correct way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package for Ubuntu editions is named either `tomcat6` or `tomcat7`.

You can install tomcat, and the associated servers, scripts and such like so:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat6
```

The `tomcat6-user` package contains a few examples on how to start user instances.

Also, I found a [link for a how-to](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu-9-04-jaunty.html) for an older version of Ubuntu, but is still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not find such a file in the unzipped folder, you can either try to find one by looking on the web or create your own file.

As a general advice, you need to pay attention to the execution order of startup scripts which can affect the success/failure of related services. Startup scripts usually contains header like the following to determine the dependency on other services during startup.

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          tomcat6
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Should-Start:      $named
# Should-Stop:       $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start Tomcat.
# Description:       Start the Tomcat servlet engine.
### END INIT INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard script provided. You will have to create you own. Here is what I usually start with: http://people.apache.org/~markt/dev/linux-etc-init.d-tomcat